# In principle if we throw a coconut at a monkey which is orbiting a Schwarzschild black hole can it escape?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, geodesics

> A space monkey is happily orbiting a Schwarzschild black hole in a
> circular geodesic  orbit. An evil baboon, far from the black hole.
> tries to send the monkey to its death inside  the black hole by
> dropping a carefully timed coconut radially toward the black hole,
> knowing that the monkey can't resist catching the falling coconut.
> Given the monkey's  mass and initial orbital radius and the mass of
> the coconut, explain how you would go  about solving the problem. What
> are the possible fates  for our intrepid space monkey? (from Sean Carroll book)

I think if the monkey is very far away then it can catch and it still will be orbiting but closer to the black hole. If coconut is fast enough to take the monkey into $r<\frac{3GM}{c^2}$ then the monkey cant maintain a circular path since circular paths are not possible in that region. It will be hard to come out from the region $\frac{2GM}{c^2}<r<\frac{3GM}{c^2}$ but if it has some sort of high energy machine which can catch the coconut and through it towards the center at very high speed then in principle it can come out. And the last case is when $r<\frac{2GM}{c^2}$ which is obvious it can't come back.

Is my answer correct?